# How to update product eav attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I want to update product custom attribute when custom module is upgraded. Attribute code is `product_brand` and i want to set it's `is_used_for_promo_rules` to 1. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used following code

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup; 
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface 
{
    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
        ) 
    { 
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    } 

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) { 
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(4,135,'is_used_for_promo_rules',1,null); 
        $setup->endSetup(); 
    } 

}
```

in `updateAttribute` 4 is entity type id and 135 is attributer id.

Comment: is your solution  worked?

Comment: @AmitBera yes it worked, upgraded module version and run setup:upgrade.

Comment: excellent.Where the issue ? Only parameters of update function ?

Answer (score 2):

**It’s pretty easy when you have the eavSetup in your setup module. It’s only necessary to execute:**

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeField, $value);
```

**For example, if I want to change the ‘position’ field value of the ‘price’ product attribute:**

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'price', 'position', 100);
```

Comment: Where did `$eavSetup` come from?

Comment: @Mageician inject `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory` in the constructor and then use `$this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);`

Answer (score 1):

For this ,you have to create **UpgradeData** script at your custom  module.

On this **upgradedata** script you need  to inject `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup` class and this class has function `updateAttribute()` which can update `is_used_for_promo_rules` field value to 1.

Comment: It will not work, I did try this a weeks ago. If you have another solution You are Most Welcome.

Comment: can u please share your code which have tried

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5gNdlR Check here

Comment: Hi i found this `updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $id, $field, $value = null, $sortOrder = null)` function and called in upgradeData script like `$this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(4,135,array('is_used_for_promo_rules' => 1),null,null);` this code but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try below UpgradeData.php script.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute
     */
    protected $_eavAttribute;


    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute $eavAttribute
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $entityType = $this->eavSetupFactory->getEntityType(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
            $entityTypeId = $entityType['entity_type_id'];
            $attributeId = $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'prefix');
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeId, 'is_required', 0, null);
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to update the attributes of the products

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;

class UpdateAttributes
{

    protected $_updateAction;

public function __construct(

        Action $action

)
{

        $this->_updateAction = $action;

}

public yourfunction(){

$this->_updateAction->updateAttributes($productId,
['is_used_for_promo_rules'=>1],0);

}
```