# How to update position of many products programmatically magento 2

Tags: magento2, reorder, sort-by-position

I have inserted 4000 products and now our client want the inverse order so how to reorder them programatically? any help please

Comment: Do you want to change the position value in the database?

Comment: i want to see in frontend the products listed from first to last added now i see the last added to first and i can't sort them by position because it will take time to attribute every product a position so is there a way to reorder them  so that i can see the first added to last added

Comment: I can suggest programmatical steps. If it could help, please let me know.

Comment: ok can you please give me those steps and thanks for your replay *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a controller's action or a custom PHP file, so that you can run your custom script to change the position.
- Get all products collection order by position in decremental order and store it as an array having product IDs and position.
- From the array above, you can easily find the biggest position and the smallest position. Now loop through the products array and assign the new positions (for this step, start from the smallest position value and every time a product is assigned the new value, add 1 to the get a new position)

For faster execution of your script, you can use **updateAttribute()** function as shown in [How to update product eav attribute in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224412/how-to-update-product-eav-attribute-in-magento-2) link.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: i will try your solution immadiatly thanks for your replay